# Calvinist Regeneration, Interpreting Colossians 2:12

Tags: faith, reformed-theology, regeneration, colossians

I am convinced that the scriptures teach of a God who is completely sovereign in salvation. I am a monergist. I can cite several passages that make me think this way. I think if you look at some of my answers on this SE, you'll see that I'm a Calvinist. However, this does not mean that I'm a blind Calvinist. I arrived where I did by many years of study and internal deliberation. I am having another internal deliberation at this point.

If we examine passages like the first half of Ephesians 2, we see that it was our nature to sin, and that we had the spirit of Satan working within us. In the same place, Paul refers to us as being dead in our sins. By all accounts, it looks to me like plain support of a Reformed interpretation of the doctrine of regeneration. In the first two chapters, we see plainly that we have been unified with Christ: he in our death, and us in His life. Because of this unity we have with Christ, God made us to be alive as He made His Son to be alive (and now, being united with Christ, we are sons and co-heirs with Christ). This all paints a beautiful monergistic picture.

However...

In the course of my studies this past weekend, preparing for a Bible study that I lead, I happened upon this verse:

> In him also you were circumcised with a circumcision made without hands, by putting off the body of the flesh, by the circumcision of Christ, having been buried with him in baptism, in which you were also raised with him through faith in the powerful working of God, who raised him from the dead.
>   (Colossians 2:11-12 ESV)

I get it most of this. Most of it still even paints a monergistic picture, with the phrase "circumcision made without hands," and the whole idea of being "raised" from the dead (the imagery being that it doesn't really involve an act of man's will that he should become alive while he is already dead).

But I have a problem with the phrase "raised with him through faith." I see a logical contradiction that I need help working through (and a non-Calvinistic perspective on the passage does not solve the problem).

Dead men cannot have faith (again, read Ephesians 2). We need to be made alive. However, this passage cites that we are raised *through faith*. What should I make of this contradiction?

I can think of two options:

1. The reformed interpretation of regeneration is wrong. Men have the capacity to believe in God before they are regenerate (Wesley's idea of Prevenient Grace would therefore be inapplicable). This simply cannot be. Again, those with faith were once under Satan's influence. A house divided against itself cannot stand; we cannot serve two masters. There was nothing in us to make us want to believe.
2. Faith must be inherent in regeneration. Not tied to it, but faith would be regenerating. This would mean that predestination would be unto faith, and I've read Reformed authors who would quite disagree with this.

I hope I've made the problem clear. I would appreciate some insight.

Edit:

Please allow me to clarify, I welcome explanations from traditions other than Calvinistic/Reformed. However, I would like these to address the basic doctrinal problem I am discussing. Please see @Eric's comment and my answer to his comment to get an idea of what I mean regarding this.

Comment: Why wouldn't prevenient grace apply? Couldn't you simply say that God enables all to come to faith, and whoever exercises that faith is saved?

Comment: @Eric The problem as I see it is an incapability to believe because it is not in our nature. In our natural state, we are dead (and working in the Spirit of Satan). Dead men are incapable of having faith. In order to have faith, our nature must change and we must be made alive. So far, P.G. sounds plausible. However, the passage says that faith is what raises us. There is a logical contradiction here. The very thing that we are raised through, we have no interest in receiving. P.G. would make us capable of receiving it, but at that point our nature has been changed.

Comment: @Eric ..contd... This would mean that it wasn't faith that regenerated us but rather the P.G., and this goes against the passage. In short, it's inapplicable because it has the same problem. If you believe in total depravity (as Classical Arminians like Wesley do), then you too are in the same boat. I'm not making a claim against P.G. here, just that it doesn't solve the problem because there is an ordering problem that it does not address.

Comment: @SanJacinto:  Maybe I'm misreading you, but could it be that you're mis-reading being "raised through faith" as "faith is what raises us?"  Faith is not the "what" that raises us, but rather the vehicle through which we are raised.  Or am I totally misunderstanding what you're saying/asking?

Comment: @Steven No, you're reading it completely fairly. I didn't mention this in the question, but I thought of that last night. In my mind, I cannot think of a means whereby this distinction solves the problem, because if you're saved through the vehicle, how does one employ the vehicle before one is capable of wanting to employ the vehicle? Perhaps if you feel you can elaborate, you could post an answer?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're struggling with some of the very concepts that have convinced me that Calvinism is an overly strict way of interpreting scripture.  It tries to fit very large, complex and abstract theological truths into nice, tidy boxes. God doesn't fit in a box. Of course that's not to say there isn't a good answer from a Calvinist perspective. If anything, Calvinist theology is good at coming up with explanations :)

Comment: @Flimzy Actually, the same must be said for _any_ interpretation of scripture. The only way to avoid that charge is to not read it. We all embrace that God is bigger than our minds. That isn't up for dispute. However, I get a little agitated when I read a comment like yours (not agitated at you, more like just a little saddened at the state of things) because it demonstrates that we each have our point where we are content to stop grappling with God's truths and let laziness take over. And I do mean _each_ of us.

Comment: @SanJacinto: I don't see it as laziness if a person chooses to stop grappling with issues that have no known definite conclusion, in favor of loving their neighbor. That's not to belittle those who choose to spend hours pondering such issues--I just don't think it is fair to presume it ought to be a priority for everyone.

Comment: I also don't think that's a fair criticism of scripture. It is fair to say that no understanding of scripture can form a complete understanding of God, but that doesn't mean that every understanding of scripture must categorize all theology into precise definitions, etc. Many people are content knowing they don't comprehend something. (Being a computer science type guy, I'm not usually that type of person--I suspect many others on this site also aren't that type :)

Comment: @Flimzy You are correct. You are right, it isn't for me to decide when somebody's met some acceptable level of "depth" in contemplating things. However, your either/or is a false dichotomy. We are not called to study the word of God xor else help and love others. It's a both-and. However, I still stand by my statement that interpreting scripture, by necessity, means to categorize it and systematize it. Indeed, scripture is incoherent and senseless without doing so. I assume you agree because you're reading this... unless someone else is reading it to you because you've plucked out your eyes?

Comment: Understanding _anything_ clearly requires some amount of categorization. So yes, I agree with you at least on some level. My personal issue with Calvinism and systematic theology is that I think it tries to invent categorizations that ought not exist, by, for instance, interpreting metaphor as literal truth. Of course I'm not interested in trying to debunk Calvinism (this site, and especially comments, is entirely the wrong place to do that anyway!)

Comment: I guess the gist of my point is: **If scripture doesn't fit into an ideology, is it the fault of scripture or of the ideology?** Most Calvinists I've conversed with are so convinced their ideology is correct that they are willing, perhaps almost eager to bend their interpretation of scripture to fit their ideology rather than the other way around. I see that as the wrong approach. I see by your question that is *not* what you're doing, so I appreciate that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3507/discussion-between-san-jacinto-and-flimzy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My friend and bible study teacher Patricia Peterson has written 2 wonderful books about the order of salvation/redemption history, election and God's decree. The *Ordo Salutis* (her 1<sup>st</sup> book) & *Whatsoever Comes to Pass ~ The Absolute Nature and Precious Comfort of God's Decree*. I pulled some of this from her 1<sup>st</sup> book The *Ordo Salutis*.

Faith comes from hearing [Rom 10:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NASB&search=Romans%2010:17). God calls His chosen ones through faith in the truth [2 Thess 2:13-14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Thessalonians%202:13-14&version=NASB). Truth is the word of God [John 17:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NASB&search=John%2017:17). The call is effectual because the elect sinner is "***in Christ***" **FROM** eternity.

We do not enter the "in Christ" relationship when we are called. God chose the elect sinner "in Christ" before the foundation of the world, in the covenant of redemption [Eph 1:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NASB&search=Ephesians%201:4); [2 Tim 1:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NASB&search=2%20Timothy%201:9). The Father elected from eternity, but He elected in Christ. There was no election of the Father in eternity APART from Christ. There has never been a time when those "in Christ" were not "in Christ". Christ is the object of our faith. Maybe some food for thought? Patrictia Peterson's books have been a blessing to me.

Comment: I think a key phrase is the "in Christ." It makes the theology make sense when it's viewed that way. I will think on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> as it is written, “There is none righteous, not even one; There is none who understands, **there is none who seeks for God** [***- Romans 3:10-11***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%203:10-11&version=NASB)

So though we were once [dead in our sins](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202:1-3&version=NASB) (and [not even able](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208:7&version=NASB) to do good, as you indicated), God [made us alive by His grace](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202:4-6&version=NASB), having [predestined us according to His foreknowledge](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208:29,%201%20Peter%201:1-2&version=NASB).

In His sovereignty, what method did He choose by which to accomplish this?  It was to be accomplished **through** faith.

> you were also raised up with Him **through faith** in the working of God, who raised Him from the dead [***- Colossians 2:12***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians%202:12&version=NASB)

This transforming event which is accomplished *through faith* is also when you become a [son of God](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%203:26&version=NASB), when Christ begins to [dwell in your heart](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%203:17&version=NASB), and when we [receive the Spirit](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%203:14&version=NASB) as God's [seal and promise](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Cor%201:22,%20Eph%201:13,%204:30&version=NASB) to us that we are in Christ and will be raised in the end.

But what is the source of this faith?  **God is!**

> For by grace you have been saved **through faith**; and that **not of yourselves**, it is the **gift of God**  [***- Ephesians 2:8***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202:8&version=NASB)

*(Now this is where many people get confused into thinking God arbitrarily predestined some for Heaven and some for Hell, and that we have no free will... but as I mentioned, God's predestination was not arbitrary - it was [based on His foreknowledge](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208:29,%201%20Peter%201:1-2&version=NASB).  But that's another topic altogether.)*

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. If you look at this question, you'll see that I agree http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7693/what-is-the-calvinist-perspective-on-regeneration/7694#7694. However, I'm still unsure that this solves the problem of men being saved through faith before they had the capability to want to have faith. I think that Dawn's answer is a little more clear that it is the unification with Christ in His death and if His death, then also His life, that makes us capable of using the faith vehicle. It still feels like there's a problem regarding the Colossians passage.

Comment: I guess for now, I will hope for more explanation and just kind of sit in a non-committal phase :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Calvinist, but I don't see a problem for Calvinism in this particular passage.  The problem that you have, it seems, arises *by assuming that being "raised with him" is the act the enables us to have (saving) faith*.  Thus, you find yourself in a contradiction, for how can we be required to have faith in order to get faith?

But I don't think that the text warrants the interpretation that being raised with him is how we are enabled to be saved.  Rather, being raised with him refers to salvation itself.

> [**Colossians 2:12 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=colossians%202:12&version=ESV)
>
> <sup>12</sup>     having been buried with him in baptism, in which    you were also raised with him through faith in    the powerful working of God,    who raised him from the dead.

Notice that the death that the reader is being raised from is not a spiritual death that keeps us from seeking God.  Paul is not talking about total depravity when he talks about death (burial) here.  He is talking about death in the sense that we died with Christ (were buried with Christ), and will be raised with Christ (as baptism symbolizes).  See also [Romans 6:3-10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%206:3-10&version=ESV) and [2 Timothy 2:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%202:11&version=ESV).

One objection to this interpretation may arise from the following verses:

> [**Colossians 2:13 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=colossians%202:13&version=ESV)
>
> <sup>13</sup>     And you, who were dead in your trespasses and the uncircumcision of your flesh, God    made alive together with him, having forgiven us all our trespasses,

Some might argue that this indicates that Paul *is* speaking about total depravity in the previous verse, and God's select regeneration of the lost from that depravity.  But I don't think we should ignore how well verse 12 parallels what Paul is talking about in Romans 6.  And I don't think that we can ignore that there *are* two kinds of death talked about in this passage: death with Christ *to* sin (v12) and death without Christ *in* sin (v13).  It seems much more natural to me to associate the being "raised with him" with the being "buried with him".

So I do not think it is necessary to say that being raised with him refers to faith enabling regeneration.  It can easily refer to our salvation itself, as long as you understand that the death we are being raised from in Paul's metaphor is not our depravity, but our death with Christ.

Comment: This was my initial thought, because we're currently studying Ephesians, and our unity with Christ in His death and resurrection is central in the first two chapters. I didn't have anything that told me that the "being raised" is what you said it is, so I "repressed" the thought. Thank you for this. I've received three good answers on this question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the text. Instead of focusing on "raised through faith" assuming this must mean our own exercised self autonomous action before regeneration, which is in my view taking what is actually being said out of its surrounding context and seeing something that really isn't there-infusing meanings that aren't there, like the aforementioned "raised to life", we should read it as it was intended.

It says in verse 11, ***"and in Him you were also circumcised with a circumcision made without hands"***. What is that if not something God does? He goes on to explain it is the working of God. The *energeia* of God (preceding) in which you were also raised up with Him (Colossians 2:12). This is not a problem when we see Our God and Savior as perfect and able to do all things for the glory of His grace. Otherwise, this would be in direct contradiction to 1 John 5:1 and many other passages.

There is also a logical order here, not just a temporal one. Not to mention the fact that we are being saved as well as having been saved at a point in time, which many scriptures indicate and often we fail to recognize in various passages (in reference to the issue whole issue)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Answer (score 1):

San,

Here is a better translation from the from the Berean Literal Bible.

> having been buried with Him in baptism, in which also you were raised with Him through the faith of the working of God, the One having raised Him out from the dead.  Colossians 2:12<

There is no "your faith"in the interlinear… A lot of translations added that.

It is God's faith at work here, Not man's.

It's through the faith of the working of God.  The one having raised him out from the dead.

The word working defined is interesting.

Cognate: 1753 enérgeia (the root of the English term "energy") – energy; "power in action"

1753 /enérgeia ("divine energy") typically refers to God's energy which transitions the believer from point to point in His plan (accomplishing His definition of progress

Again it's all God's doing.  We are his workmanship Created in Christ Jesus.

The more we understand the grace of God the more we understand it's all of  Him.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see the issue. First of all, there is a passive voice in which the subject is patient, it means we are raised along with Jesus through faith in the Power of God. If we understand that nobody is asked to believe in the power of God as the object of the saving faith. We believe IN CHRIST.

This being said, the faith Paul is taking here is the Subjective Jesus’ faith in God’s Power to raise him. He covered us, he had faith for us. If you see the passage closely, you will see that the context is talking about Jesus' work on the cross and how his action obtained forgiveness for us.

So if we understand Paul is talking about Jesus' action, and how he procured our forgiveness through faith in Gods Power, calvos it doctrine of pre-regeranaration is not refuted here. That is how I see it.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Can you please provide evidence to support your views?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, I can't keep quiet. The more I read this section of Colossians, the more amazed I am that people can read it an think that it says anything contrary to "God saved me by His power alone to the Glory of His grace". If you read the in which you were also raised up with Him through faith" and ignore everything else it's no wonder how one could miss the whole context. But read the entire passage and he's clearly saying that God is the one acting to change our hearts by his powerful working.

> <sup>**9**</sup> For in Him all the fullness of Deity dwells in bodily form, <sup>**10**</sup> and **in Him you have been made complete**, and He is the head over all rule and authority; <sup>**11**</sup> **and in Him you were also circumcised with a circumcision made without hands**, **in the removal of the body of the flesh by the circumcision of Christ; <sup>**12**</sup> having been buried with Him in baptism, in which you were also raised up with Him through faith in the working of God,** who raised Him from the dead. <sup>**13**</sup> When you were dead in your transgressions and the uncircumcision of your flesh, **He made you alive together with Him**, having forgiven us all our transgressions, <sup>**14**</sup> **having canceled out the certificate of debt consisting of decrees against us**, which was hostile to us; **and He has taken it out of the way, having nailed it to the cross. <sup>**15**</sup> When He had disarmed the rulers and authorities, He made a public display of them, having triumphed over them through Him.** (Colossians 2:9-15)

I just don't see anything like, "But Jesus is waiting so patiently for you to exercise YOUR faith so he can hopefully save you and cause you to be born again after you do your part. Then He'll do His part. Amen! Cause our God is a warm Fire?! Instead, ***“For this reason I have said to you, that no one can come to Me unless it has been granted him from the Father.” John 6:65***

Comment: If you want to add additional information to an answer that you have already given, please use the [edit] under the answer to do so.